# Partial Text in RichTextBox to Bold

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to make some of the `SelectedText` in a RichTextBox Bold. I used this :

```
 private void RichTextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
 {
     if (e.Modifiers == Keys.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.B)
     {
         if (RichTextBox1.SelectedText.Length == 0)
         {

         }

         RichTextBox1.SelectedText = Font.Bold;
     }
 }
```

But I get this error :

> *Cannot implicity convert type 'bool' to 'string'.*

I don't know what to do :\

Answer (score 3):

[`Font.Bold`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.font.bold.aspx) returns `boolean` .

```
Type: System.Boolean
true if this Font is bold; otherwise, false.
```

There is no *[implicity conversation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx)* from `boolean` to `string`.

Try with using [`Font Constructor (Font, FontStyle)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bdte89fc.aspx);

```
RichTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font(RichTextBox1.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `RichTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font(RichTextBox1.Font, FontStyle.Bold);`

instead of `RichTextBox1.SelectedText = Font.Bold;`

Font.Bold is a boolean property indicating whether the current Font is bold.
In this case the current Font refers to `this.Font` or the main Font for the control in which the RichtTextBox is located.

RichTextBox1.SelectedText is a string so that's why it doesn't work.
You don't need to set the SelectedText, but the SelectionFont.